# RowCount,Table must Exist, Delete All Rows from Table keywords from Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am new to robotframework and I am trying to get the hang of the keywords of DatabaseLibrary. I am getting error at 3 of such keywords.

1) I am using rowcount keywords as below-

```
 ${rowCount}   Row Count   <sql query>
```

And I always get ${rowCount}=0 irrespective of the number of rows in my table.

2) I am using Delete All Rows From Table as below-

```
  Delete All Rows From Table <Table_Name>
```

And I get ORA-00911: invalid character   but if use the same table with   other keywords like Query ,it works fine.

3) I am using Table Must Exist as below-

```
 Table Must Exist <Table_Name>
```

And I get ORA-00942: table or view does not exist  but this table is very much there.

Please help me find what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I believe a colleague told me there were issues, at the very least with the Row Count keyword.

However, for all three options there are easy solutions, which you've even hinted at in your question by using Query or Execute SQL Script

1)

```
${result}=    Query    Select count(id) from table
${rc} =    ${result[0][0]}    #Play with this as I forget exact syntax
```

2) Put your delete script in a test scripts folder with your tests and call it using Execute SQL script.  You could also use Query to perform a select query before and after to confirm expected states.

3) Again perform a query against the table you're expecting to be there, a simple row count on id would do for this purpose.  You could set a variable based on the result and use this again later if required.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but it doesnot solve the purpose for me fully.I was trying to use various keywords like rowcount less than/greater than X to verify I was getting correct no of rows in table but since row count is always 0 so my test fails as any number is being compared against 0.

Same goes for other 2 .I can go by alternate route but if these commands can work for me then its better.

Comment: Either what you're doing is incorrect in terms of syntax or the keywords are broken.  I've offered you a way to achieve what you want, I would suggest attempting these methods to confirm whether the issue is with the library or your attempt to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues.
I use cx_Oracle.

With the Table Must Exist keyword my problem was the same.
I dont really understand why, but first I have to use Encode String to Bytes keyword.
And I need to use a DatabaseLibrary 0.8 at least, because earlier versions didnt have solution for cx_Oracle. These solved this issue for me.

But with Delete all rows from table I still have problems.
Because this keyword puts a ; at the end of the line and it passes on that line to execute query if I  understand weel, so it still causes an ORA-00911 error for me.

With Execute Sql String and the command DELETE FROM tablename you can have the same results, but it will work this way.

I hope it helps a little